# How to solve Swift warning: "Constant 'value' inferred to have type 'AnyClass?' (aka 'Optional<AnyObject.Type>'), which may be unexpected"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-warnings

Can't figure out why the compiler throws this warning

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

```
func configure(with classesReuseRegistry: [String: AnyClass?]) {
    var collectionView = UICollectionView() // Temp collection var for testing purposes
    
    for (key, value) in classesReuseRegistry {
        collectionView.register(value, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: key)
    }
}
```

I also want to clarify, this warning was not present before. I had similar code on [this library](https://github.com/acotilla91/MultiCollectionView/blob/master/MultiCollectionView/Classes/MultiCollectionViewCell.swift#L36) and it was never a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can silence the warning by modifying your code to:

```
func configure(with classesReuseRegistry: [String: AnyClass?]) {
    var collectionView = UICollectionView() // Temp collection var for testing purposes
    
    for classDict in classesReuseRegistry {
        collectionView.register(classDict.value, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: classDict.key)
    }
}
```

I think that the warning is caused by having `AnyClass`, which is a type alias, as dictionary value, and not a value type like Int, String, ...